# 'DiscordAPIError: Unknown Message' when deleting message upon a reaction

Tags: javascript, bots, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make a menu in JavaScript with my Discord.js bot. So far everything works perfectly, except when I apply the reaction that removes the message. The message gets deleted, but this error is spammed in the console:

> ```
> DiscordAPIError: Unknown Message
> ```

I checked in other areas and was careful to delete the message only once, but even so, I get the impression that the bot is attempting to delete it several times. I've also tried return to try to stop the code, and put a timer to the delete method. None of these attempts have resolved the error.

This is the code I'm using:

```js
message.channel.send(exampleEmbed2).then(sentEmbed => {

    sentEmbed.react('');  
    sentEmbed.react('✅');
    sentEmbed.react('❌');

    client.on('messageReactionAdd', (reaction, user) => {

        if (!user.bot && reaction.emoji.name === '') {
            sentEmbed.delete();
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! How can you be sure that messageReactionAdd is fired with '' multiple times?

Comment: I have no idea, normally the code runs only if there is a new reaction

Comment: I think what @JeroenHeier is saying, is that with this code, everytime someone reacts to any message with , this runs your code. You probably want to add more control, especially on the message the reaction is attached to.

Answer (score 2):

As [Gruntzy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3393195/gruntzy) has explained...

> ...with this code, everytime someone reacts to any message with , this runs your code.

As opposed to attaching another listener to a nested `messageReactionAdd` event, use [Reaction Collectors](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ReactionCollector). These are meant for this purpose and will only fire upon reactions on the message you attach them to.

Consider this example which uses the promise-based version of a collector (see [`Message.awaitReactions()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=awaitReactions))...

```js
message.channel.send(exampleEmbed2)
  .then(async sentEmbed => { // Somewhat awkward to switch to async/await here, but much cleaner.
    await sentEmbed.react('');
    await sentEmbed.react('✅');
    await sentEmbed.react('❌');

    const filter = (reaction, user) => ['', '✅', '❌'].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && user.id === message.author.id
    const [reaction] = await sentEmbed.awaitReactions(filter, { maxMatches: 1 });
//        ^^^^^^^^^^
//  This is a destructuring
//  assignment. It takes the
//  first (and only) element
//  from the Collection/Map.

    if (reaction.emoji.name === '') await sentEmbed.delete();
//  Do stuff with the other reactions...
  })
  .catch(console.error);
```